# Specific formatting for some entries of a glossary

Tags: macros, glossaries, emphasis

I use the `memoir` class. In my glossary, I need to emphasize *certain* terms (and descriptions), but let the others in roman.

The command is `\glossary{term}{description}` so I tried to do `\glossary{\emph{term}}{\emph{description}}` and the emphasis is there. But, and that's my problem, the emphasized terms are then sorted amongst the Symbols. That's because of the \emph command which is interpreted literally by makeindex, I think.

Is there a way to do that? Can I create another specific/alternative command `\glossaryemph` for this formatting? How?
memoir.cls has these lines (l.8660-8667) which seem relevant to me, but I'm really not sure:

```
\newcommand{\memwritetoglo}[5]{\endgroup}
\newcommand{\@ctualm@mwritetoglo}[5]{%
  \immediate\write \memglofile{\string\glossaryentry{#1\@nameuse{memglsact\m@mgf}
                {\string\memgloterm{#2}}{\string\memglodesc{#3}}
                {\string\memgloref{#4}}\@nameuse{memglsnf\m@mgf}}{#5}}%
  \endgroup}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\memwritetoglo\@ctualm@mwritetoglo}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\makeglossary % glossaire, fichié généré: .gls

%generate .gst style file
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.gst}
% Output style parameters
preamble "\\begin{theglossary}"
postamble "\n\\end{theglossary}\n"
item_0 "\n\\glossitem"
delim_0 "{\\memglonum{"
encap_suffix "}}}"
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
% Input style parameters
keyword "\\glossaryentry"
\end{filecontents}

% general glossary styling
\renewcommand{\memgloterm}[1]{\textbf{#1}} % glossary term in bold
\renewcommand{\memglodesc}[1]{\hspace{2ex}#1} % glossary description: distance
\renewcommand{\memglonum}[1]{} % no glossary (page) numbers

\begin{document}
Some text.

\glossary{v.}{voir}
\glossary{\emph{Aa.Vv.}}{\emph{Autori vari}}
\glossary{OJLS}{Oxford Journal of Legal Studies}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: emphasized entry is under the Symbol heading]

Comment: And why not using the `key` argument to get proper sorting? `\glossary(A){\emph{Aa.Vv.}}{\emph{Autori vari}}`

Comment: Because I didn't know I could do that! I tried to mimic the `\index{Princes etrangers@Princes étrangers}` syntax without luck  – to solve another issue with diacritics, but the idea is roughly identical, i.e. separate the key and the term's name. I didn't find so much documentation about `glossary`, because it's not a package I think (?), where can I find that?

Comment: Page 313 of the `memoir` [`user guide`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) describes the complete syntax for `\glossary`.

Comment: Terrifying, I obviously read these pages, too quickly… and I was trying desperately to elaborate a much more complex solution. By the way, is `\glossary` a `memoir` command ? Or is it rooted in TeX?

Comment: LaTeX2e's kernel has very basic versions of `\glossary` and `\makeglossary`. The `memoir` class defines improved versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `key` argument to specify the proper sorting order; for example,

```
\glossary(Aa){\emph{Aa.Vv.}}{\emph{Autori vari}}
```

A complete example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\makeglossary % glossaire, fichié généré: .gls

%generate .gst style file
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.gst}
% Output style parameters
preamble "\\begin{theglossary}"
postamble "\n\\end{theglossary}\n"
item_0 "\n\\glossitem"
delim_0 "{\\memglonum{"
encap_suffix "}}}"
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
% Input style parameters
keyword "\\glossaryentry"
\end{filecontents}

% general glossary styling
\renewcommand{\memgloterm}[1]{\textbf{#1}} % glossary term in bold
\renewcommand{\memglodesc}[1]{\hspace{2ex}#1} % glossary description: distance
\renewcommand{\memglonum}[1]{} % no glossary (page) numbers

\begin{document}
Some text.

\glossary{v.}{voir}
\glossary(Aa){\emph{Aa.Vv.}}{\emph{Autori vari}}
\glossary{Ab}{Ab test}
\glossary{OJLS}{Oxford Journal of Legal Studies}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

The resulting Glossary:

[image]